# georasters pip install on windows fail

Tags: python, python-3.6, raster, pyproj

Following the steps given in https://github.com/ozak/georasters, 
but having the same traceback for both steps of the pip install process.
Blows up when "collecting pyproj.." with some issue with "msvc.py".

```
Collecting pyproj (from georasters)
  Using cached pyproj-1.9.5.1.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    using bundled proj4..
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "c:\users\javie\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 490, in_find_latest_available_vc_ver
        return self.find_available_vc_vers()[-1]
    IndexError: list index out of range
```

Can anybody help?
thanks

Comment: Do you have visual c++ installed on your computer? Might be you need to download that as `msvc.py` seems to be unable to locate it

Comment: That's a shot in the dark, but I'm wondering if `pip install --upgrade setuptools` will help. Judging from the code, current setuptools shouldn't throw this exception on this line.

Comment: i just had installed visual studio build tools, and try again, and give me the follow error

Comment: `Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\javie\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\compat\__init__.py", line 73, in console_to_str
    return s.decode(sys.__stdout__.encoding)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa2 in position 44: invalid start byte`. @Norrius, also, already had try upgrade setuptools, and wont work.